# Select TOP N not working in MS Access 2010 Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Its not returning me 1 record as expected.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationVersion 
FROM [All Documents]
ORDER BY Iif(IsNumeric([ApplicationVersion]), Clng([ApplicationVersion]), 0) DESC
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: JET's `TOP` behaves like SQL Server's `TOP WITH TIES`. Try `ORDER BY [... what you want ...], DocumentIDOrPrimaryKeyColumn`

Comment: I found the problem , if you have two rows having same ApplicationVersion then it will return you two rows insted of one. SELECT TOP dose not work..strange..

Answer (score 0):

I have found new issues with "SELECT TOP 1" in Access 2010, that were NOT there in 2007:

1. If a query returns more than one record 'at the top' in the result set, **where the sorted fields are the same**, TOP 1 will return **all** those records, even if unsorted fields are different. I worked around it by adding another **sorted** field (a timestamp), which would never be the same.
2. Adding criteria to a query that uses a "TOP 1" **subquery** does not work. For example:

   > SELECT [my_top_1_query].* FROM [my_top_1_query] WHERE my_id=1234

   **does not work**.
   If I add the criteria directly to [my_top_1_query], then it does work.

I think that changes have been made to JET in A2010, in the way it assembles such queries.